# How to add extra argument to Callback_field function Grocery CRUD Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I've been trying to add extra parameters to a callback_field function so I can execute additional queries to databases before outputting a field but I failed. 
Here's my code buddies :

```
 function table($table , $iditem = null) {
```

`...
// I want to add $iditem variable to addperiodedeclaration_callback function
  $gcrud->callback_field('Periode',array($this,'addperiodedeclaration_callback'));`

```
... }  
function addperiodedeclaration_callback ($value = '', $primary_key = null,$iditem) {


try {
    $sql = "SELECT  PeriodiciteTVA FROM  client where idClient = ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($iditem));
        echo $iditem;
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        switch ($query->row()->PeriodiciteTVA) {

            case 'Mensuelle' :
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $options = array(
                    'Selectionner le mois' => 'Selectionner le mois',
                    'Janvier' => 'Janvier',
                    'Février' => 'Février',
                    'Mars' => 'Mars',
                    'Avril' => 'Avril',
                    'Mai' => 'Mai',
                    'Juin' => 'Juin',
                    'Juillet' => 'Juillet',
                    'Août' => 'Août',
                    'Septembre' => 'Septembre',
                    'Octobre' => 'Octobre',
                    'Novembre' => 'Novembre',
                    'Décembre' => 'Décembre');
                return form_dropdown('Periode', $options, $value, "id='Periode' class='chosen-select'");
                break;
            case 'Trimestrielle' :
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $options = array('Selectionner le Trimestre' => 'Selectionner le Trimestre',
                    '1er Trimestre' => '1er Trimestre',
                    '2e Trimestre' => '2e Trimestre',
                    '3e Trimestre' => '3e Trimestre',
                    '4e Trimestre' => '4e Trimestre'
                );
                return form_dropdown('Periode', $options, $value, "id='Periode'  class='chosen-select'");
                break;

            case 'Annuelle' :
                return '<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" value="' . $value . '" name="NumTVA">';
                break;
            default:
                return 'Selectionner une periodicite' . var_dump($query->row());
                break;
        }

    }else
        return 'Selectionner une periodicite';
}catch ( mysqli_sql_exception $e) {}}
```

I want to make a query with the $iditems variable